# Why is my C++ text file parsing script so much slower than my Python script?

Tags: python, c++

I am currently trying to teach myself c++, and I am working on file IO.  I have read through the cplusplus.com tutorial, and am using the basic file IO techniques I learned there:

```
std::ifstream  \\using this to open a read-only file
std::ofstream  \\using this to create an output file
std::getline  \\using this to read each line of the file
outputfile << linecontents \\using this to write to the output file
```

I have an approximately 10MB text file containing the first million primes, which are separated by whitespace, 8 primes to a line.  My goal is to write a program which will open the file, read through the contents, and write a new file with one prime number per line.  I am using regular expressions to strip the whitespace on the ends of each line, and to replace the whitespace between each number with a single newline character.

The basic algorithm is simple: using regular expressions, I trim the whitespace on the ends of each line, and replace the whitespace in the middle with a newline character, and write that string to the output file.  I have written the 'same' algorithm in c++ and Python (except I use the built-in strip() function to remove leading and trailing whitespace), and the Python program is much quicker!  I expect the opposite; I would think that a (well-written) c++ program should be lightning fast, and a Python program 10-20 times slower.  Whatever optimization is done behind-the-scenes in Python, though is making it way faster than my 'equivalent' c++ program.

My regex searches:

```
std::tr1::regex rxLeadingTrailingWS("^(\\s)+|(\\s)+$"); //whitespace at beginning or end of string
std::tr1::regex rxWS("(\\s)+"); //whitespace anywhere
```

My file-parsing code:

```
void ReWritePrimesFile()
{
    std::ifstream readFile("..//primes1.txt");
    std::ofstream reducedPrimeList("..//newprimelist.txt");
    std::string readout;
    std::string tempLine;

    std::tr1::regex rxLeadingTrailingWS("^(\\s)+|(\\s)+$"); //whitespace at beginning or end of string
    std::tr1::regex rxWS("(\\s)+"); //whitespace anywhere
    std::tr1::cmatch res; //the variable which a regex_search writes its results to

    while (std::getline(readFile, readout)){
        tempLine = std::tr1::regex_replace(readout.c_str(), rxLeadingTrailingWS, ""); //remove leading and trailing whitespace
        reducedPrimeList << std::tr1::regex_replace(tempLine.c_str(), rxWS, "\n") << "\n"; //replace all other whitespace with newlines
    }

    reducedPrimeList.close();
}
```

However, this code is taking minutes to parse through a 10 MB file.  The following Python script takes approx 1-3 seconds (haven't timed it):

```
import re
rxWS = r'\s+'
with open('pythonprimeoutput.txt', 'w') as newfile:
    with open('primes1.txt', 'r') as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            newfile.write(re.sub(rxWS, "\n", line.strip()) + "\n")
```

The only notable difference is that I'm using the built-in strip() function to strip newlines instead of using a regular expression. (Is this the source of my terribly slow execution time?)

I'm not sure at all where the horrible inefficiency in my program is coming from.   A 10MB file should not take this long to parse through!

*edited:  originally showed the file at 20MB, it's only 10MB.

Per Nathan Oliver's suggestion, I used the following code, which still took about 5 minutes to run.  This is now pretty much the same algorithm I used in Python.  Still not sure what's different.

```
void ReWritePrimesFile()
{
    std::ifstream readFile("..//primes.txt");
    std::ofstream reducedPrimeList("..//newprimelist.txt");
    std::string readout;
    std::string tempLine;

    //std::tr1::regex rxLeadingTrailingWS("^(\\s)+|(\\s)+$"); //whitespace at beginning or end of string
    std::tr1::regex rxWS("(\\s)+"); //whitespace anywhere
    std::tr1::cmatch res; //the variable which a regex_search writes its results to

    while (readFile >> readout){
        reducedPrimeList << std::tr1::regex_replace(readout.c_str(), rxWS, "\n") + "\n"; //replace all whitespace with newlines
    }

    reducedPrimeList.close();
}
```

second edit:  I had to add an additional newline character at the end of the regex_replace line.  Apparently the readFile >> readout stops at every whitespace character?  Not sure how it works, but it runs an iteration of the while loop for each number in the file, not for each line in the file.

Comment: The comparison is not fair. You're using regex in C++ twice and the regular expression itself in C++ is more complex than python's.

Comment: A closer C++ equivalent to `line.strip()` would be `boost::trim(line)`.

Comment: Several minutes still seems really high.  Try commenting out the second regular expression and time again, per @deepmax's point.  I'm wondering if there is a difference in how file IO is happening too.  Going to delete my initial answer, though, as it was wrong from reading the question much too fast.  Sorry!

Comment: Have you profiled your C++ program? Are you compiling with optimizations on?

Comment: `I am currently trying to teach myself c++, `  I think you really do need to answer whether you are running this code with optimizations turned on.  Beginners usually make the mistake of building the code with the default options, which in almost every case, does **not** produce optimized code.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I turned on optimizations (The ones a quick google search suggested: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/8tt43355(v=vs.100).aspx) The new file is being written at approximately 10KB/sec. *edit the program just finished running, it took around 5 minutes.

Comment: That link is for Visual Basic. For Visual C++, if you're using a project created using one of the standard wizards, switching the solution configuration to `Release` is enough to turn on optimizations (for starters). Did you do that?

Comment: @bogdan Yeah, that's how I tested the code, which took ~5 minutes.

Comment: Have you tried calling std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false)? By default, iostreams can be slow if they are syncing with the c standard IO. Although your slowdown is pretty vast, so it's probably something else, but worth a shot.

Comment: Well, if you're *sure* you're in release mode, then you're probably running the app under the debugger, that is, you're probably pressing `F5` in the IDE. Don't do that if you want performance. Run the program either by pressing `Ctrl+F5` in the IDE, or by starting the resulting exe directly from a command prompt.

Comment: @Anna That applies to the *standard* streams, that is, things like `std::cout`. I don't think it will affect this example in any way.

Answer (score 5):

The code you have is slower because you are doing two regex calls in the C++ code.  Just so you know if you use the `>>` operator to read from the file and it will ignore leading white space and read until another white space character is found.  You could easily write your function like:

```
void ReWritePrimesFile()
{
    std::ifstream readFile("..//primes1.txt");
    std::ofstream reducedPrimeList("..//newprimelist.txt");
    std::string readout;

    while(readFile >> readout)
        reducedPrimeList << readout << '\n';
}
```

Comment: I don't know how to add code to the comments, but I made your suggestions and it's still taking a really long time.

Comment: @JackGeiger Code really isn't supposed to be added to comments.  Did you to any timings to compare how long each different approach takes?  As Paul stated above to you have any optimizations turned on/ how are you compiling the code?

Comment: @JackGeiger:  There are two bottlenecks to file I/O:  1) obtaining the data and 2) Converting from textual representation to internal representation.    Search the internet for "stackoverflow c++ optimize read file".

Comment: @NathanOliver I turned on optimizations (The ones a quick google search suggested: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/8tt43355(v=vs.100).aspx.  The new file is being written  at approximately 10KB/sec.  *edit* the program just finished, it took maybe 5 minutes to run (compared to 1-3 seconds on Python)

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Thanks for the advice, I'll definitely look into that.